# Auto sync iOS application (Objective-C) local database with MySQL database

Tags: ios, mysql, objective-c, core-data, synchronization

Already I built an iOS application that pull json data from a server(PHP MySQL), now i need to change this architecture to this schema to make my application work online/offline : [image]

there is any suggestion for solution for Auto Sync ?

Comment: Good luck. Syncing means drinking. Two-way syncing is a complex problem, and the answers depend on many details of how your app works and what kind of data you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to follow the steps :

1. Upon starting up, application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: you need to check for your [internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3597085/1889814). If not available, inform the user to enable it.
2. After registering an internet connection you need to connect to your server and retrieve the json and map it to the database model. I suggest you use [JSONModel](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel) to parse the json and [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) to easily save that data to your database.

That would solve all your needs for auto-sync.

Comment: thanks but i need to allow users to work with the application whene  there is no connection or slow connection, and auto sync data whene internet comes back like auto sync with couchbase lite

Comment: then just register for notifications when the user connects to the internet with http://stackoverflow.com/a/3597085/1889814 and sync then..

-(void) checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice
...